# Is the '/r/' sound 'alveolar' or 'palatal' or 'retroflex'?

Tags: phonetics

In phonetic classification, Is the '/r/' sound 'alveolar' or 'palatal' or 'retroflex'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly related to English or English learning. This question belongs to Linguistics SE, but the OP should include more details. This question is probably too broad or too basic for Linguistics SE.

Comment: It depends on the accent/ dialect and region.

Comment: I vote to move it. It embodies a few common misconceptions on a surprisingly complex topic, I'm sure it would receive a good answer over there.

Comment: It depends whether you're asking about /r/ (and which language) or [r]. There is a lot of information out there on the internet that explains this.

Answer (score 1):

Most English accents don't use /r/ (an alveolar trill) The exception being some Scottish and Welsh accents, and even then it is not universal.

The usual "r" sound in English is an alveolar approximate /ɹ/.